# Android hashmap displaying incomplete values

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I have a problem displaying my map values. This is my code :

**CustomAdapter:**

```
Map<String, List<Show>> map;
List<Map.Entry<String, List<Show>>> list;

public WorldShowsAdapter(Context context,
                         Map<String, List<Show>> map) {
    this.context = context;
    this.map = map;
    list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
}

@Override
public Map.Entry<String, List<WorldShow>> getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_show_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvShowName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShowName);
        viewHolder.tvShowName2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShowName2);
        viewHolder.btViewAllShows = (MyButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btViewAllShows);
        viewHolder.rvShows = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rvShows);
        viewHolder.llBackground = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llBackground);
        viewHolder.showsManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        viewHolder.rvWorldShows.setLayoutManager(viewHolder.showsManager);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

 Map.Entry<String, List<Show>> entry = this.getItem(position);
    viewHolder.tvShowName.setText(entry.getKey());

    List<Show> shows = entry.getValue();

    for (Show s: shows) {
        viewHolder.tvShowName2.setText(s.getShowTitle());
    }
}


private void display(RecyclerView rvWorldShows,
                     Map<String, List<WorldShow>> catShows,
                     List<WorldShow> showData) {

    WorldDetailsShowsRecyclerViewAdapter showsAdapter
            = new WorldDetailsShowsRecyclerViewAdapter(context, catShows, showData);

    if(showsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
        rvShows.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rvShows.setAdapter(showsAdapter);
    } else {
        rvShows.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

I'm only getting the last value.

When I changed to this:

```
   viewHolder.tvShowName2.setText(entry.getValue().toString());
```

It's displaying this:

```
[Talk=[
com.test.models.Show@fe6eb61, 
com.test.models.Show@f0ff686, 
com.test.models.Show@88cfb47]
```

Any ideas why I'm getting these? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Post your complete `CustomAdapter` class code

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan updated my post. Pls. check. thanks!

Comment: Firstly, I believe you should iterate over entrySet. Secondly entry.getValue().toString() shows you a reference to the Show because it can't convert it automatically to any string, so either add toString method to Show class or extract each field from show separately.

Comment: @jaroslawj any sample how to do it? I'm newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why I'm getting these? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
[Talk=[
com.test.models.Show@fe6eb61, 
com.test.models.Show@f0ff686, 
com.test.models.Show@88cfb47]
```

is the `toString()` of `List<Show>`, and `com.test.models.Show@fe6eb61` is `toString()` of `Show`. If you override `toString()` in `Show`, and return something meaningful, you will get something like

```
[Talk=[
 "aaa", 
 "bbb", 
 "ccc"]
```

Probably you want to use an `ExpandableListView`, instead of a simple `ListView`, where the `Group` is the key of your HashMap, and the `List<Show>` are the Group's children

Comment: I am displaying this in listview and then the children to be displayed in a horizontal recyclerview

Comment: then you are doing it wrong. The `RecyclerView` has its own adapter, which is made of `List<Show>`. The `ListView` shouldn't care to display information about the `Show`s

Comment: So what will be my approach to do this? I'll update my adapter

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want every children of the ListView to be a RecyclerView

Comment: Hi Blackbelt 2 I appreciate your help. I want to display distinct Categories and respective children of each category.

Comment: what's the difference between WorldShow and Show? It would be much easier if you could describe what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setText` use append method of TextView to show all data in single TextView :

```
for (WorldShow s: shows) {
        viewHolder.tvShowName2.append(s.getShowTitle()+"\n");
    }
```